# Silverlight UI effects

Tags: c#, silverlight, user-interface, silverlight-5.0

I want to build a nice looking UI with Silverlight, something that keep moving in a delicate manner ([like this intro](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/))

I know of course this is possible through the Animation features of Silverlight, but they seem to me a bit too exhausting. I'm looking for some ready-to-use UI animation.

As I recall, jquery offers quite a few UI menus (etc.) that are really easy to use.

I've searched quite a bit for effects library, or tutorials, but I couldn't find anything helpful.

Is my only option is writing Storyboard and build my animations from scratch?

Is that considered OK or I'm just reinventing the wheel here for no reason?

Does it make jquery a better choice for fancy UI web applications? (I've never used it , just read about it)

Comment: Can someone explain to me why I got down voted? it seems to me like a constructive question..

Comment: the question has multiple pieces to it and the title of the post seems a bit misleading for what you are really asking.

Comment: What better title would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storyboards and animations aren't that bad to learn. They are daunting at first (because they can be verbose), but if you just take some time to understand them, they are fairly straight forward. You can try some third party control suites like Telerik which have some animation/transition functions but I'd suggest diving in and understanding how they work.

The best way to try to learn the animations is to think of what you want to do first (something simple) and then just research/figure it out. Googles great for this! Do somethign easy at first of course.

View the sample Silverlight animation browser at microsoft to get started... [Sample Animations](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/Silverlight/SampleBrowser/index.htm#/?sref=animation_ovw_intro)